# Why does iptables keep looking for the next rule when an extension target is used?

Tags: networking, iptables, linux-networking

The man page of iptables says that if a rule does match, then the next rule is specified by the value of the target.

So if I have two rules like this:

```
iptables -t mangle -I FORWARD -s 192.168.1.10 -j DROP
iptables -t mangle -I FORWARD -s 192.168.1.10 -j MARK --set-mark
```

I expect that since MARK rule is matched first and specifies the final target, the DROP rule is never consulted. But in realty, it is and the packets are dropped.

However, if the rules are

```
iptables -t mangle -I FORWARD -s 192.168.1.10 -j DROP
iptables -t mangle -I FORWARD -s 192.168.1.10 -j ACCEPT
```

Then the DROP rule is never consulted because the ACCEPT rule short-circuited it.

Is it the case that only the special targets like ACCEPT, DROP prevent iptables from keep looking for the next rule? But I don't see it mentioned anywhere in the man page, did I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two kinds of targets in IPTables chains: Terminating and Non-terminating targets.

`ACCEPT`, `REJECT`, `DROP` are terminating targets. They terminate processing of the packet in the current Netfilter hook.

`MARK`, `LOG` and many others are non-terminating targets. They create some action based on the packet, and then proceed to the next rule.

In your example, `-j MARK` is the first rule in the chain. It marks the packet, and then moves to next rule, which drops the packet.

If you want to mark and accept the packet, then you need something like:

```
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.10 -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.10 -m mark ! --mark 0x1 -j DROP
```

Also, it is not a recommended practice to DROP packets in the `mangle` table.

Answer (score 1):

Rules are processed in order.

By using the `-I` flag when adding your rules you actually insert each new rule as the first rule in the chain and push  all existing rules 1 position down in the order they are processed.

Thus the last rule you add with -I gets evaluated first.

Typically to add the rules and ensure  they are processed in a more intuitive order, most scripts and people use the `-A` flag to append each new rule as the last rule , behind all existing rules.

Use `[sudo] iptables -L -v -n` to display the active rules in the order the kernel evaluates them   (although some people like `iptables-save` better). Often when discussing configurations it is useful to use the `--line-numbers` option as well
to number lines. Refering to rule #X makes discussing them somewhat easier.
**Note:** NAT rules are included in the `iptables-save` output but have to listed separately by adding the `-t nat` option i.e, `[sudo] iptables -L -v -n -t nat --line-numbers`.